# Chrome Devtools console copy object is [object Object]

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using `Chrome Version 114.0.5735.199 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Whenever i console.log and i try to copy object the copied object returns `[object Object]`

This is very frustrating, anyone knows a fix for this?

[image]